# Should i use null for the ImageObserver parameter of the Graphics.drawImage() function?

Tags: java, image, graphics, awt, drawimage

I have the following variables: `Image avatar;` and `URL url;`

In the constructor, I set:

```
this.url = new URL("http://www.robottiger.com/user.PNG");
```

and

```
this.avatar = ImageIO.read(url);
```

Then in..

```
public void paint (Graphics g)
```

..is it correct to use the following?

```
g.drawImage(avatar, 20, 410, null);
```

Or should the `null` be `this` instead?

Comment: Just a suggestion, don't override your `paint(...)` method, if you using Swing, for such a task, override [paintComponent(...)](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/painting/#swing) instead, both are okay, though they are meant for different things, don't know that much of a detail, else I be posting my answer for that :-)

Answer (score 3):

The 4th argument is the observer, the object to be notified as more of the image is converted. It can perfectly be null, assuming that is really only useful if you're fetching the Image parameter asynchronously.

Answer (score 2):

The constructor you are referring to for `drawImage()` is as follows:

```
public abstract boolean drawImage(Image img, int x, int y, ImageObserver observer)
```

The fourth argument is just the image observer, which is the `object to be notified as more of the image is converted.` so it is fine for it to be null.

Answer (score 2):

In contrast to the other two replies, I recommend that if you have an `ImageObserver`, **use it** and make no presumptions as to whether the image was loaded synchronously (e.g. [`ImageIO.read(URL)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#read%28java.net.URL%29)), loaded asynchronously (e.g. [`Toolkit.createImage(URL)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Toolkit.html#createImage%28java.net.URL%29)) or generated in memory.

Answer (score 0):

If you're loading `Image` across the network (not from the file system, or constructed by program) and not explicitly waiting to load, you need to use an `ImageObserver` to make sure to completely draw an `Image`. Other than that- just use null. It should be fine.